# Failed conversion of a QImage image to a CV image

Tags: qt, opencv

I am new to both opencv and opencv. What I am doing is to convert a `QImage` image to an opencv `Mat` image, and then display both of them. Here is my code for this conversion:

```
     i = new QImage("lena.png");
    QImage lena = i->scaled(labW,labH,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);

    //Original
    QImage lenaRGB = lena.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
    ui->imgWindow->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(lena,Qt::AutoColor));

    //method 1
    Mat lena_cv, out;
    QImage lena2 = lenaRGB.rgbSwapped();
    QImage swapped = lena2;
    swapped = swapped.rgbSwapped();
    lena_cv = Mat(swapped.width(),swapped.height(),CV_8UC3, swapped.bits(),swapped.bytesPerLine()).clone();
    namedWindow("CV Image");
    imshow("CV Image", lena_cv);

    //method 2
    Mat out2,out3;
    out2.create(Size(lena2.width(),lena2.height()),CV_8UC3);
    int width = lena2.width();
    int height = lena2.height();
    memcpy(out2.data, lena2.bits(), sizeof(char)*width*height*3);
    cvtColor(out2,out3,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    namedWindow("CV Image2");
    imshow("CV Image2",out3);
```

Both of the above two conversions cannot yield desired images, as shown below:
[image]

It is also noted that the conversion cannot proceed without using `rgbSwapped`, i.e.,:

```
lena_cv = Mat(lenaRGB.width(),lenaRGB.height(),CV_8UC3, lenaRGB.bits(),lenaRGB.bytesPerLine());
```

because: 
[image]

[image]

The resulting image `lena_cv` cannot be displayed. If an additional step to convert `lena_cv` to BGR format using `cvtColor` before image display:

```
    Exception at 0x7ffdff394008, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1  
   (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) at c:\opencv-3.2.0
    \sources\modules\core\src\opencl\runtime\opencl_core.cpp:278
```

This indicates the post conversion to BGR fails. I am not sure RGB to BGR conversion (of QImage) is necessary or not for converting QImage to CV image. 
Can anyone help identify the issue with the above codes. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? QtCreator has that feature, so I recommend using it and giving us more clues.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I am still not familiar with the feature. I will give more error information later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "skew" in the third image is almost likely a result of assuming that each scan line occupies exactly `width*3` bytes.  There's typically a "stride" (or "steps") factor with each row in many image formats image such that the number of bytes per row is on some 4-byte or 16-byte boundary.  Fortunately, QImage has a helper method called `bytesPerLine` that tells you how long each source row is.

So instead of this:

```
memcpy(out2.data, lena2.bits(), sizeof(char)*width*height*3);
```

Do this:

```
unsigned char* src = lena2.bits();
unsigned char* dst = out2.data;
int stride = lena2.bytesPerLine();
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
{
    memcpy(dst + width*3*row, src+row*stride, width*3); // copy a single row, accounting for stride bytes
}
```

All of this assume it's the QImage that has the stride bytes and not the target Mat image you are transforming the bits too.  If I have this backwards, then adjust the code to account for the steps member of Mat. (I don't see you using this, so I'm willing to be the above code is what you need).

The "blue" image is mostly likely just the RGB color bytes needing to be swapped for every pixel.  Not sure why you are calling rgbSwapped unless that was the effect you were going for.  Oh wait, you're probably referring to that noise effect at the bottom of the image.  I'm willing to bet you need to think about "stride" bytes as well here too.

Comment: For the second image, in addition to the blue color, it also has artifacts of streaks appearing at the bottom, which are not fully displayed above.

Comment: I just noticed that too.  I'm willing to bet its another variant of the **stride** in each row of the source image.  Adjust your code to copy "one row at a time" using the technique I show above.

Comment: I do see that `cv::Mat` has a constructor in which you can specify a "step" parameter.  That might be all you need as well if you are still hoping to copy the image in one shot.

Comment: I  have tried you solution. It works, but still get 'blue' color. The reason I use 'rgbSwapped' is because opencv works on BGR not RGB, and without that conversion, I always got an error "The program has unexpectedly finished" for some reason.

Comment: Can you post a complete (yet minimal program) including the "lena.jpg" file that repros the problem?

Comment: Not familiar with OpenCV, but is it possible that its crashing because `out3` hasn't been allocated yet?